# How to write a unit test with data fetching, that alters data based on respone in vuejs?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to write a unit test for a function that does an async call, but it doesnt seem to alter the data prop, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Check the code below:

```
getSomething() {
  MyService.getThis().then(
    response => {
    this.status = true;
  }
).catch(error => {})
}
```

TestCase:

```
describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
// To ignore the created hook, but this doesnt work, any idea?
  spyOn(CustomerData, 'created');
  spyOn(MyService, 'getThis').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(list));
});

wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  propsData: {
    data: {}
  },
});

it('should work', () => {
  wrapper.vm.getSomething();
  expect(wrapper.vm.status).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
}
```

The status should be true, but it is false, but if I print the value of status in the getSomething() function it is indeed true. I have no idea what the issue can be.

update:

In the test case I wrote

```
it('should work', async () => {
await wrapper.vm.getSomething();
expect(wrapper.vm.status).toBeTruthy();
}
```

and this seems to work. Is this a good way to solve it? Would love to hear other solutions.

Also I am very interested if it is possible to ignore the created hook, I havent been able to figure that out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that running inside `getSomething()` is asynchronous. `MyService.getThis()` returns promise, and its execution takes time, in case if you fetching some data from remote serivce.

So first of all you need to return promise from `getSomething()`

```js
getSomething() {
  return MyService.getThis()
    .then(response => { this.status = true; })
    .catch(error => {})
}
```

And inside the test you need to return promise outside, to let jest know that your test is asynchronous.

```js
it('should work', () => {
  return wrapper.vm.getSomething().then(() => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.status).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Or as you mentioned in the edited part you can use `async` version:

```js
it('should work', async () => {
  await getSomething();
  expect(wrapper.vm.status).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just think it is weird that, since I am mocking the response, the answer should come straight away. Or am I wrong in this? Does it still have some delay?

Comment: Even if you mocking your answers - all `.then` handlers of the promises will be called after current thread of execution will be finished - that means, that `.then` handler in original code will be called after `expect` statement execution.